# Windows Server as web server with VPN and DNS resolving incorrectly - options?

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, web-server

I originally posted this on the [networking site](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57419/windows-server-as-web-server-with-vpn-and-dns-resolving-incorrectly-options), but have been advised to post here:

I have my own HP Gen8 server running Windows Server 2012 R2.

I've worked in I.T all my life but struggle sometimes with networking so wondering what my options are here.

The server does many things, but one aspect of the server is it's a web server (hosting websites in IIS). It is also a DNS server and runs on a static IP address.

I'd like the server to run constantly on a VPN (I run the PIA client on other devices), however running the VPN on the server causes my external IP address to change, therefore all websites are inaccessible and DNS does not resolve.

What are my options for being able to run a VPN on this box? Another network card? If so, how do I route the traffic? Up to now I've had a VM running but that's a very heavy resource to use for the sake of running a VPN to manage certain tasks. Likewise, setting the VPN on a router would also cause the same issue with the external IP address.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does this server need to be connected to a VPN?

Comment: It doesn't *need* to, but it's a personal home server so I would like all traffic to go through a VPN.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense if your box is a server and you have clients pointing browsers to it over the web, either you have to create a separate VPN server to have your clients pointing to your internal virtual private network, or you'll have to hire a VPN service that allows you to serve content and name resolution through their exit address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another NIC would not help much. Even on 1 NIC you can still send packets around VPN to specific IP ranges, it's all about defining routing priorities. But I found that working with partial VPN coverage is always a little bit fragile.

1) Easiest and most robust solution would be to leave all VPN stuff inside VM, and leave all non-VPN services outside. Lower maintenance, lowest chance of errors.

2) You can do partial VPN coverage with OpenVPN (what I had experience with), where you can explicitly define network ranges which should go through VPN (you can start from "route-nopull" directive). I am sure similar feature could be available with other VPN software.

Comment: Okay, have given the bounty to you, as you be fair from many sites you have at least provided an answer. I guess it's my only choices, thanks for the response!